# psftp put is throwing error <dir>: open for write: failure when filename is not provided in destination location

Tags: sftp, putty, psftp

I am using psftp's put command to upload files. I am not providing the filename in destination location assuming that the file will be copied with the same name. Here's the help page of put command

```
psftp> help put
put [ -r ] [ -- ] <filename> [ <remote-filename> ]
Uploads a file to the server and stores it there under
the same name, or under a different one if you supply the
argument <remote-filename>.
If -r specified, recursively store a directory.
```

If I try to use PUT without filename in the destination location, psftp throws the error **open for write: failure**

```
psftp> open user@host
Using username "user".
Remote working directory is /
psftp> put <file_name> ./<dir>/
/<dir>: open for write: failure
```

Whereas if I provide the filename in the destination location, it works

```
psftp> put <file_name> ./<dir>/<file_name>
local:<file_name> => remote:/<dir>/<file_name>
```

Why does the PUT command require filename in the destination location?

Answer (score 1):

What the help page means that the whole `<remote-filename>` argument is optional, not filename part of the argument.

So you can do this

```
put <file_name>
```

It uploads the file to the current remote working directory, under the same file name.

---

But you cannot do:

```
put <file_name> ./<dir>/
```

---

You can do this though:

```
cd ./<dir>
put <file_name>
```